# DBCA : Cannot see new database instance under the reconfiguration of databases

Tags: oracle

I used DBCA to create a new database instance. After creation of the instance.

I startup the DBCA again to reconfigure this particular datbase. But however i cannot see this database.

I also tried to use

dbca -slient -adddb NewDB

But it prompt me DISPLAY variable not set properly.

After i set DISPLAY variable.
It prompt me again saying -slient is not a valid command line argument.

What is the issue and how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by looking at environment variables; I have encountered a situation where I created DB from one ORACLE_HONME and could not see it with DBCA from another ORACLE_HOME.

Do other xwindows tools work?  E.g. is it a DBCA issue or something more fundamental?

Can you stop and start the Instance from the account you are running DBCA from?